# Unix/Linux C++ debugger that supports STL containers?

Tags: gcc, debugging, eclipse, ide

Currently I am using gcc-4.3.6 and Eclipse IDE for c++ development. I want to debug my project in Eclipse with `gdb`. I am having a hard time debugging code when it contains STL containers. Also I am not using STL directly, I have wrappers for each container.

I know we have to use pretty printing for looking into STL containers, but it is not working in Eclipse. I have worked in Visual Studio in the past. I migrated to `gcc` and Eclipse because compilation time in VS is too much wrt gcc. However, the debugger in VS is very good. I don't know much about `gcc` and Eclipse. I just want to know if there is a similar debugger in linux or unix.

Comment: Think about asking this on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: This is technically on-topic here, since it's asking about a \*nix tool; if you want it moved to SO, flag it

Comment: I had to say, Microsoft's VS and compiler product is most advanced in the world, I don't see a single product in opensource world competitive with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the debugging features provided by `gdb` are based on the set of symbols that comes with your compiled code.

Actually there isn't a debug version available for the STL, but there are at least 2 portings that can add debug symbols to your code:

http://www.stlport.org/

http://code.google.com/p/stl-debug/

`gdb` without debugging symbols is useless, so you have to use a "debug version" for each library that you are using in your code if you want to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try KDevelop's or QtCreator's debugger. They interact with gdb's latest python support and support browsing thought STL containers as well as Qt's.

(Disclaimer: i haven't tried them much, gdb's support for remote debugging sucks too much for that)